# 句読点として「，．」を使うのは推奨されないか？

Tags: 討議, 編集

僕の[こちらの質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/2126/revisions) に関しまして．

> 日本語の句読点と段落を修正

として，主に 「，．」を「、。」に差し替える内容の編集を頂きました．この「，．」を用いることは，僕自身としては一貫して用いているスタイルであり，一般的ではないものの（特に技術系では）それなりに見かける習慣であると認識しています．

瑣末なスタイルについて他の利用者の方の手を煩わせたくはないため，もし一般的にいって「，．」の使用が推奨されない/読みづらいのであれば，以降自分のほうで置換してから投稿することにしようと考えています．細かいことに関する硬性な規則のそぐわしいサイトではないと思うので，ここでコミュニティとしての結論を出してほしいというような話ではないのですけれど，皆様はどうお考えでしょうか．

Answer (score 16, accepted):

私はどちらのスタイルでもよいと思います。

Comment: どちらでもよい、に同意です。上の質問本文を読んでいる時も、「，．」が使われていることに最後まで注意が向かなかったほど、個人的には気にならない違いです。「ちょっと違う書き方をする人なんだな」と思いはしますが、回答に影響を与える違いではない、と思います。

Comment: 本件からは少し離れてしまいますが、質問者／回答者以外の他人による編集が行きすぎると、コミュニティとしての信頼関係に悪影響を与えるとおもいます。本質に影響しない些細な問題点や個人のスタイルには踏み込まない、という合意形成がされると良いかと考えています。

Answer (score 2):

申し訳ございませんでした。句読点を修正した者です。いったん、句読点を「.」と「,」のものに戻ささせていただきました。

私としては、他の多くの質問と書式を統一したほうが質問が読みやすくなり、回答されやすくなるのではないかと思い善意の意図で行いましたが、余計なことをしてしまったかもしれません。もし気分を害されたようであれば、大変失礼いたしました。

Comment: こちらこそ話を大きくしてしまった感があり申し訳ありません．書式の統一というのも尤もに思われ，これを機にコミュニティにどう見られるのかを確認できれば，というようなことでこちらに質問させていただきました．回答されやすくなるようにと編集を頂きましたこと，この場をお借りしてお礼申し上げます．

Answer (score 2):

そもそも、「，．」は句読点ではありません。コンマとピリオドです。

参考: 論文の句読点にピリオドとかコンマを使うのはなぜ? - Togetterまとめ

- http://togetter.com/li/420594

個人的には「、。」を使うべき(強いshould。mustではない)だと思ってます。

Comment: ここでは（他に適切な言い回しを思いつけなかったので），「句読点」を「日本語で文の途中，また文末に挿入する約物」程度の意味で用いていましたが，仰るとおり非標準な言い方かもしれません．どう言い換えるとよいかちょっと思いつかないので一旦そのままにしますが…
なお，僕自身が「，．」を使うのは，慣れに加えて，なんとなく「、。」より静かな印象があって気に入っている，また欧文を混ぜる時に馴染みやすい，といった程度の軽い理由からです．もし強い should で「、。」を使うべきとお考えの理由を追加していただければ，僕自身やその他の皆様の参考にできると思います．