# ネコ語の語尾を編集して「ですます体」にするのは問題ないか？

Tags: 討議, 編集

[SlidingPaneLayout でスマートフォンとタブレットで挙動を統一させたいにゃ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/5520/30)

についてです。これまでにない、ネコ語の語尾（「~にゃ」）を特徴とする文体の質問です。それに合わせて回答やコメントの方もロールプレイング的なノリのやりとりになっています。

純粋に情報を得たくてこのQ&Aを読む場合、文体のもつ人格がノイズになって気をそらされてしまうように思います。このような文体は、一般的な「ですます体」に編集で変えてしまって問題ないでしょうか。

それとも、こうした語尾は句読点の種類と同じように個人的な執筆スタイルの範疇で、編集すべきではないものでしょうか。

関連

- [句読点として「，．」を使うのは推奨されないか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1464/30)

Answer (score 24):

一般的でない語尾を変えることは、質問の改善につながります。質の改善を目的とした編集行為は承認されるべきです。しかし、件の質問の場合、編集行為が投稿者アカウントのアイデンティティ破壊につながることを考慮すべきかもしれません。

私としては、投稿編集をする場合は、質問が読みやすいか読みにくいか、質問が技術的な主題にフォーカスしているか、のみが厳しく見られ、語尾など、遊びの部分を除去するかどうかの判断は — *もし収束する結論が「除去する」で同じだとしても* — あくまで自由判断であって欲しいです。編集による語尾除去が義務のように施行されることがなくとも、それが質問の質を落としていれば、投票やクローズ票の仕組みで淘汰されると考えるからです。

特に、投稿後初期段階に限っては、技術者の理解度やバックグラウンドがわかるような文章の揺れや勘違いは、特別不快でない限り、残されるべきかと思います。回答者が質問者の意図を判断する指標になります。

参考までに、私は質問を編集するとき、以下の可能性を視野に入れます。

1. 回答候補者を、望ましくない方法で絞ってしまっている可能性
   → 同じ文化（暗黙の了解）を持つもののみを回答者候補としていないか。 変な質問には、変な質の回答者を呼び込みやすい
2. 回答の評価軸に、技術的な評価だけではなく、暗黙ルールの順守が加わる可能性
   → 質問では明かされない、暗黙のルールを守ったかどうかが、プラス票評価の対象となってしまわないか
3. 回答者の品位を傷つける可能性
   → 回答者が、匿名システムで守られたぬいぐるみと独り芝居をしているように映ることにはならないか
4. 閲覧者の気を害し、ノイズの多さから読まれなくなる可能性
   → 一般的なページから雰囲気があまりにかけ離れることになった場合、文章が読まれなくなることにならないか

私が[件の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/5520/30)を見たときは、致命的な偽りがあるわけではありませんし（例: 「初心者です」「小学生です」等）、技術的な主題にフォーカスしていますので、「にゃ」ぐらいは、（残念ながら）日本らしい技術者コミュニティにおける例外的方言の範囲で良いだろう、回答者がしっかりしていれば 1.～4. までは問題とならないだろう、と思いました。

rin さんのような、ロールプレイ性の強いアカウントは、 Stack Overflow のシステム上、既にしかるべきボーダラインに立たされていると言えます。 長期的に活動される場合、「『にゃ』等を付けたことでマイナス票を誘引してしまった質問」を、「プラス票を入れざるを得ないような、良い回答や、役に立つ質問をすること」で相殺するようにしなければ、自動的に質問資格を失うことになります。

- [ヘルプ センター > 質問にあたって > 私のアカウントからの質問が受け付けられなくなったのはなぜですか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

一方、回答の一つにあるような「おじさんが」「お譲ちゃんは」の下りは、ノイズとしては大きすぎるように感じました。技術的な回答として良い回答かもしれませんが、質問者に対しこのように声かけをすることは、一般的にも通報対象の可能性があります。上記のリストの 4. の悪い結果がでたのですが、原因は語尾だけの問題ではない気がします。

Comment: +1 本ケースはID＋アイコン＋文体が強く紐付いているようで、まさに指摘されている"アイデンティティ破壊"がちょっとだけ気になりますね。回答投稿の方は質問文体に呼応させたと思うので、責めるのはちょっとだけ酷かなとも感じます。P.S.:[編集履歴](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/5520/revisions)をみてちょっと笑ってしまいましたｗ

Comment: 最終的にはサイト上のすべての行動は自由判断にもとづくものです。その判断材料とするために、色んな人の考え方をメタで洗い出せればと思います。 /// 一つの見方として: ロールプレイ・アイデンティティの維持と、今後訪れる多くのユーザーに読解の労力をかけさせないようにすることを天秤にかけると、私の中では訪問者への配慮の方が勝ちます。アカウントが長生きしなくても、削除されない限り投稿は残り続けます。

Comment: @yohjp 「責める」という単語は、問題を個人の問題かどうかに帰着させてしまい、コンテンツの問題がぼやけてしまうように思います。個人の問題に帰着させずに「責めるべきでない」とするアングルとしては「利用者の一般的な傾向なので仕方ない（だからシステマチックな対策が必要）」や、「質問に呼応する内容なので、適切な回答である」でしょうか。

Comment: 注目記事になってしまっているのでコメントで追加させてください・・・ @yohjp 編集時は「にゃん公、行末に半角スペース2個ぐらいは付けようよ」と考えていたと思われます。 回答者に対しての文は、責めているつもりはなくて、投稿者のノリを一般人のノリで受け取った上でのコメントです。 @ ento ゆっくり考えてみると、これは、このサイトがアニメキャラクターアカウントを受け入れるか否か、につながるんですね。 [Wikipedia の編集統計](https://ja.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%E7%89%B9%E5%88%A5:%E7%B7%A8%E9%9B%86%E5%B1%A5%E6%AD%B4%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%9A%E3%81%84%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8&limit=500&offset=0)をみると、それ系のページは頻繁に更新されるので、そういう雰囲気のほうが、サイトが気軽に使える（親しみやすさ）ということになるのかもしれないとは思います。 日本らしさ、にそれを含めるかどうかですね・・・ /// といっても、最終的には、管理コストが一番考慮されなければならないのだろうなと感じています。

Comment: ID+アイコンだけのアニメキャラクターアカウントの場合と、文章を見ただけでそれと分かるような場合とで扱いは分かれそうです。訪問者の大半がどう受け止めるか、にかかってはいると思いますし、例えばアニメ関係の日本語Q&AサイトがStack Exchange上にできたら、そのコミュニティーでまた独自に判断することになると思います。

Answer (score 10):

個人的にはこうしたユーモアを多様性と受け取っても良いと思いますが、
やはり一般的な日本語に編集するのが望ましいと考えました。

StackExchangeがブログに載せた以下の **公式見解** が参考になるかもしれません。
[Non-English Question Policy « Blog – Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/)

> - **Direct programmers to native language resources.** Users who post non-English questions should be gently directed to programming forums in their own language. Community should form around the gravity of native human languages. (see: Chinatown, Little Italy, etc.) Feel free to post links to appropriate human language-specific resources.
> - **It is not our goal to teach English.** It is our goal to teach programming. If the post has salvageable English and makes some modicum of sense, it should be edited and improved just like any other post. If it does not, it should be closed.
> - **The asker has to put effort into the question.** Barging into an obviously English dominated forum and insisting on posting a question in another language is no different than the “do my work for me” sort of programming questions — the worst possible sin on Stack Overflow in my humble opinion. You want us to give you answers? Then prove that you’ve put some effort into the question, and you can begin by politely asking it in the language this community is formed around.

今回のケースに適用すると、以下のような感じでしょうか。

- ネコ語のコミュニティに行くように親切に促しましょう。
- もし解釈可能なら直ちに日本語に直しましょう。そうでなければクローズすべきです。
- 質問者は質問自体に注力すべきです。

---

余談。宗教上の理由でネコあるいはネコ語がダメという方もいます。もしかするとゴキブリ語を嗜好する人間もいるかもしれませんが、僕は拒絶します。
この場にそうした**本質ではない問題**を余計に持ち込まない方が良いと思いました。

Comment: 「個人的にはこうしたユーモアを多様性と受け取っても良いと思います」この通りです。[We don't hate fun](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)は公式見解です。

Comment: @jmac その記事に挙げられている、ユーモアを歓迎するかの判断基準をあてはめると:
1. ネコ語はヘルプセンターにあるガイドラインの範囲内か → Yes? (分かりにくいと判断するかによる) 
// 2. コミュニティの評価は肯定的か → No (スコアが-4) 
// 3. ネコ語であることで、仕事に役立つ何かを学ぶことにつながっているか → No (とあるキャラクターの存在を知りましたが、プログラミングには関係ない) で、1/3点。今後の評価次第で2.がひっくり返った場合2/3点。諸手をあげて歓迎、という部類では無いかなと思います。

Comment: ここで挙げられている「公式見解」は(英語のフォーラムにおける)非英語の質問に対してどうすべきかを述べているもので、今回の件に適用するには不適切ではないでしょうか。「ネコ語」は語尾が特殊とはいえ何の困難もなく日本語として解釈できるので、英語版における非英語とは立場が明らかに異なります。

Comment: まぁ、そもそもネコ語は言語ですらないのですから。。尚、余興としては方言として捉えても良いかもしれませんね。その場合[Are British/International English terms acceptable? (e.g. 'brackets' instead of 'parentheses') - Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252503/are-british-international-english-terms-acceptable-e-g-brackets-instead-of/253878#253878)という話題もありました。これはこの回答とは逆の結論になりそうです。

Answer (score 8):

ネコ語のままでいいと思います。

件の質問を見ましたが、一般的な日本人なら文意の理解に支障はないと感じました。
この情報を求めている人がいたとすれば、その人にとってネコ語はたいしたノイズにならないと思います。
この程度のノイズを取り除こうとすれば、関西弁のような方言や些細な言葉使いまで編集しなければいけなくなるのではないでしょうか？

人間性や趣味嗜好や文化的背景と、その人がもたらす情報の有用性は関係がありません。
表面的ノイズを嫌って有用な情報を排斥してしまうのはもったいないと思います。

Comment: 「支障はない」と感じられたこと自体に疑問を投げかけるものではありませんが: 方言や細かな言葉づかいについて問題が出てきたら、ネコ語とは別の問題として議論・判断すればよいと思います。また語尾部分に有用な情報があるわけではないので、そこを編集しても有用な情報を排斥することにはつながらないのではないかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

その質問には価値があると考えた人がいれば、編集してしまっても構わないと考えます。ただ、常に編集「すべき」とまでは主張しません。

おそらく大抵のケースで、品質が低い質問投稿と評価されて、反対投票で勝手に沈んでいくと考えるためです。内容が技術的に有用であれば（ネコ語のような）表現方法を問わず賛成投票が付く可能性はありますが、スタート時点で不利なのは間違いないと思います。この選択をしたのは投稿者自身ですから、放っておけばよいというスタンスです。

Comment: 表現方法で技術的内容が覆い隠されて、本質を評価した投票が付かない可能性もあります。私はどちらかというと、可能性にまかせずサルベージできるものは積極的にサルベージしたいと考えます。それは投稿者への善意というより、SOにとって有用なコンテンツを取り逃さないためです。（これは私の個人的スタンスであって、放っておけばよいというスタンスはそれはそれで尊重します）

Comment: この回答は「我関せず」という態度を言語化しただけなので、@ento さんのようなスタンスの方がSO上に居れば、ほかの低品質な質問と同様に編集されていけば良いと考えています。

Comment: (なんだかツッコミにくいコメントをしてしまった気がして反省しています。) 常に編集「すべき」とまでは主張しない、というのは編集する人もしない人もいてよいし、場合によって編集した方がよいことも、そうでないこともある、ということですね。

Answer (score -4):

余所でやってくれとしか。
ただ編集するよりはクローズして質問丸ごと削除した方がいいようなケースだと思います。

Comment: 少し討論・討議としては、文面が短く説得性にかけています。そのためマイナス票が付いていると思われます。

Comment: 削除した方がいいのはなぜですか？技術的な問題を具体的に説明している点で、サイトにとってまったくなんの価値もない質問というわけではない、と私は思います。

Comment: なりきり（語尾のにゃー）は本人の強い意志で行われています。これを第3者が編纂すべきではありません。そしてスタックオーバーフローにそのような非技術的ノイズを許容すべきではありません。丸ごと削除が妥当です。

Comment: なるほど。「本人の強い意志」であるかは、聞いてみないと分からないものではないでしょうか。削除前に編集してよいかを聞く、または編集すると同時にコメントで問題ないかを聞く、という段階を踏むのはどうでしょう。