# 文体違法改悪改ざんに付いて。

Tags: 討議

お手間を　かけます。
"

昨今、

少なくとも　一部投稿に対して、
提出意図に　悖る、
改悪改ざんを　認めました。
"

しかも、

此に付いて、
一切の　契約では、
縛り得ない　著作者人格権への、
侵害が　見られました。
"

抑も、

著作者人格権は、
国際法、国内法、
共に、

個人に　認められた、
個人権権の　一部で、

なん人も　国内で、
此を　犯す、
事は、
許されない　ものです。
"

其処で、

こうした　規約にも、
悖る　法令遵守違反に対して、

規約の　無力さ、
其の　他に対する、
周知徹底を　行いつつ、

再発防止に対しての　討議を、
此処に　提出、
致します。
"

既に、

解答を　多数、
頂いては　いますが、

本案件の　ポイントたる、
「実際に　現状、
其れ等だけでは　防ぎ切れていず、
横行すら　している。」
と　いう、
実体に対する　動議、

そうした　ものですので。
"

故に、

効果が　結果として、
みられない、
過去の　答申には、
紐づけ得ない　もの、
と、
進言します。
"

問題点は　現状です、
過去では　ありません。
"

確実に、

動議冒頭で「昨今、」と、
言及させて　頂いたと、
思いますが。

### 追記

では、

一例を　挙げ、
説明　致しましょう。
"

此方を、

何方か　但一人でも、
一意に　確定的に、
読めますか？

「いれたてのおちゃ、」
"

此は、

CMでも　大々的に、
取り上げられた、

もはや　常識的な、
意味合いを　示す、
ものです、

ご存知ありませんでしたか？
一意に　読めますか？
"

勿論、

何らかを　用いて、
意味文節を　明示的に、
示せば、

此の　様な、
問題は　発生しません。
"

しかしながら、

此の　区切りを、
句点で　行えば、
如何でしょう？

触れるまでも　ありませんね。
"

さて、

では　何故、
此の　様な、
事が、
発生するのでしょうか？
"

其れは、

一重に　情報格差の、
存在による　ものです。
"

勿論、

読み手と　書き手には、
意味という　情報に付いて、
保有量の　格差が、
存在しています。
"

併せて、

此の　意味情報は、
曖昧記載への　補正効果をも、
持ち合わせて　います。
"

ですので、

先筆　慣用句では、
読み手は　一意に、
読めても、
書き手では　読めない、

そうした　事を、
誘発するのです。
"

長くなりましたが、

上記は、
此の　文体を、
構成付ける、
唯の　一端に、
過ぎません。
"

勿論、

他にも　様々な、
ものを、
示唆に　入れた、
結果として、

読み手配慮として、
此の　文体は、
固定付けられて　います。
"

ですので、

決して　唯の、
主観や、イタズラや、恣意的衝動、
等で、
記している　ものではなく。
"

ちゃんと、

改善に　紐付けられた、
現時点で　辿り着いている、
私における　最善、
と、

ご理解　頂ければ、
幸いです、

如何でしょうか。

Comment: CC BY-SAライセンスですけど。

Comment: ご投稿　有難うございます。
"

伺います、

国際法、国内法、憲法、
等を　上回り、
停止し得る　ものですか？
"

もし、

差にあらない　場合、
根拠とし、断行すれば、
直ちに　違法行為です。
"

後記、

如何なる　場所においても、
其の　規約に、
よらず、
国内においては、

著作権主張　並びに、
著作者人格権回復は、
法的に　認められる、
旨、

有償内で　正式有資格弁護士に、
対面にて　確認済みです。
"

此処で、

ご自愛　召される、
事を、
お進めさせて　頂きます。

Comment: あらゆる法律が強行規定であると勘違いしていません？

Comment: 著作権者の許諾があれば、著作の改編は認められますが、あなたは認めないということですか？

Comment: いえ、

「全てを　全く、
認めない、」
と　いう、
趣旨では　ありません。
"

勿論、

私の　選択より、
より　良い、
ものを、
お持ちの　方は、
おられます.

無論　認めますよ。
"

是非、

そうした　方からの、
ご指導、ご鞭撻、
等は、

逆に　賜りたい、
位です。


いわずもがな、

其の　表れとして、
こうして　ご指導を、
賜りに、
質問させて　頂いたのですしね。
"

ですので、

合意の　上での、
改善も、(×改ざん)、

私　個人としては、
肯定したいですね。
"

しかし、

今回の　改悪違法改ざんは、
此の　外ですよね？

意味開示要求も、説明要求も、
なく、
意図も　汲まず、

一方的な、
思い込み、決め付け、先入観、
等から、

確認も、許諾も、
取らず、

しかも　改悪を、
施しましたよね？
"

流石に、

「此は　少なくとも、
行き過ぎだ、」
と、

抗議するしか　ないように、
思いますよ、

如何ですかね。
"

やはり、

一方的な　レイプ的な、
ものは、
大凡ですか、
宜しくも　ないのでは？

Comment: htb様へ、

どういう　事でしょう？
無知指摘でしょうか？
冒涜ですか？

Comment: あなたの同意した個別サイトの利用規約が、ご主張の法律の規程より優先されますよ、ということです。

Comment: いいえ、法が　優先されますよ。

Comment: 質問には編集履歴があり、質問した内容から編集されたことは明示的にわかります。私自身はいくつかの回答はnoubleさんが投稿したものではなく、改善されたものという認識をしています。それでもご自身の投稿を勝手に変えられて不満ですか？

Comment: あらゆる法律が強行規定であると勘違いされているわけですね。私からはこれ以上何もありません。

Comment: keitaro_so様、

ご質問　有難うございます、

〉勝手に変えられて不満ですか？

解答は　Yesです。
"

私は、

如何なる　専決権も、
犯される　事を、
昰とは　し得ません。
"

其れは、

私の、
肉体の　処遇も、
意思も、権利も、性的対応も、他も、

等しく　同様です。
"

解り易くしましょう、

此が　文面でなく、
性的専決権でも、
同様に、

「他者からの　専決権蹂躙を、
許容しろ、」
と、
貴方は　いい得ますか？
"

如何なる、

個人権利の　蹂躙に対しても、
私は　許容を、
致し得ません。
"

求めるならば、

同意確認が　あって、
当たり前だ、
と、
思いますが、

如何でしょう。
"

他方、

お申しは、
「他に　既に、
横行しているのだから、

新たに　レイブ犯罪、
詰まり　他者意思蹂躙を、
犯しても　無実だ。」
此と、

如何せん　同列に、
感じ得て　しまいす、

何故でしょうか。
"

如何でしょう、

此は　貴方の、
認識内なのでしょうか？
"

其れとも、

否定し　撤回なされますか？

Comment: 関連: [ネコ語の語尾を編集して「ですます体」にするのは問題ないか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1649/19110)

Comment: nouble さん、文体の話ではなく一般の話として、スタック・オーバーフローにおける編集のルールを誤解なさっているかもしれないので、ご確認をお願いしたいです。もちろん著作者人格権は日本の法律で認められていますが、著作者の意思に関わらず改変をしてはいけないという訳ではなく、著作者の同意があれば改変が認められています。そして nouble さんは利用規約で同意をなさっています。このためスタック・オーバーフローのユーザーはサイトのルールのもとで nouble さんの投稿を編集することができます。

Comment: nekketsuuu様、

何故　そう、
示唆されたが、
よく　掴めないのですが、

此までを　受け継ぎつつ、
更に　加筆を、
致します。
"

元より、

其方　主題は、
「お巫山戯"的"な　語彙への、
編集権に対する、
方針模索、」
では　ないかと、
お見受けしますが、

此は　如何でしょう。


尚、

失礼が　あれば、
お詫び　致します。
"

もし、

ならば　根源的に、
主体に　差異が、
見られないでしょうか？
"

此方は、

其のような　お巫山戯"的"な、
ものに対して　ではない、
と、

承知して　おります。
"

お立場上、

困惑を　されている、
お辛い　状況なのは、
察して　余りある程、
では　ありまますが。
"

さりとても、

人権侵害は　如何せん、
許容　致し兼ねる、
事を。
"

どうぞ、

ご理解　頂けますよう、
平に　請願、
致します。

Comment: nekketsuuu様、

こそっと　見たような、
訳では　ないのですが、

先ほど　チャットでの、
ご発言を　拝見しました。
"

誠に、

ご心労を　おかけしている、
点に付きましては、
謝罪　致します、

申し訳ない。

Comment: 何故でしょう、

契約では　違法行為までをも、
許諾さしめし得ない　事は、

受託殺人が　合法と、
ならない　事を、
見ても、

明白だと　思います。
"

勿論、

現役弁護士の　正式見解でも、
著作者人格権所か、諸作権をも、

「権利者の　意思に、
反してまでは、
剥奪し得ない、」
と、

明言されて　いますしね。
"

なのに、

何故　当たり前を、
ご理解すらも　頂けないのですか？

解りませんよね。

Comment: ↑を　質問欄に、
追記しようと　しましたが、
私の　責任外理由で。
"

しかも、

とても　強く、
嘲るような、

不愉快極まりない、
ふざけた　メッセージと、
共に、
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjviygfJDgV_40t7q73pkWDznu1f

拒否されました、
"

抑も、

文頭が　困窮者意識を、
逆撫でしています、
"

しかも、

「国内から　国内への、
インターネット回線において、
遮断を　試みている、」
と　示す、
とは。
"

『「日本会員限定向けサービスにおいては、

其れは　もはや、
ほぼ　全員に対して及ぶ、」
と　いう、
事を、

お前なら　スルーするだろ？』
とまでも。
"

さも、

いわんばかりな、
あり得ない、
不実丸解りの　文面には、
酷く　失望しました。
"

勿論、

強い　遺憾を、
示し、
最上級に　抗議します。
"

示して、

いい　事と、
悪い　事が、
示すべき　相手と、
示さざるべき　相手とが、

あるのでは　ないですか？

Comment: お忙しいのでしょうね、

下記　文章が
時間を　経ても、
追加が　間に合わないようですね。


なれば、

お手伝いさせて　頂くほかに、
ないでしょうね。
"

受けて、

私　自ら、
回復させて　頂いて、
おきますね。
"

　　　　　　　　　記
此処で、

他討議中での　user10678様の、
発言を、
参照　頂けるよう、
進言　致します。
"

尚、

発言使用について、
許可を　頂いて、
いないため、

参照に　留める、
次第です。
"

さて、

此方において、
「言語、」を　「文体、」と、
置き換えた　場合、

どの様な　知見に、
至るでしょうか？
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　以上。

Answer (score 10):

質問を投稿する際、

[image: 質問を投稿する]

ここからリンクされている[利用規約](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing)に

> ### Subscriber Content
>
> You agree that any and all content, including without limitation any and all text, graphics, logos, tools, photographs, images, illustrations, software or source code, audio and video, animations, and product feedback (collectively, “Content”) that you provide to the public Network (collectively, “Subscriber Content”), is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow on a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive basis pursuant to Creative Commons licensing terms (CC BY-SA 4.0),

と説明されていて、これに同意しているはずです。
これにより、質問・回答・コメントなどあなたの全ての投稿は全世界のStack Overflowに対して

- perpetually / 永久的に
- irrevocably / 取り消し不可能な形で
- royalty-free / 無償で
- non-exclusive / 非独占的に
- licensed / 使用することを認める

とされています。

その上で、使用を認められたStack Overflowがどのように扱うかについては、その先の部分に

> This means that you cannot revoke permission for Stack Overflow to publish, distribute, store and use such content and to allow others to have derivative rights to publish, distribute, store and use such content. The CC BY-SA 4.0 license terms are explained in further detail by Creative Commons,

と説明されていて、これにも同意されています。
これにより、Stack Overflowの他の利用者があなたの投稿に対し派生させたものに対し

- publish / 公開
- distribute / 配布
- store / 保存
- use / 使用

することを認めています。
端的に言えば、あなたはStack Overflowの他の利用者に対して編集し公開することを認めました。

「改悪改ざんを　認めました。」とのことですが、独占的な所有権を主張されるのであれば間違っています。Stack Overflowに対して自ら同意したはずの利用規約に違反していることを自覚してください。

---

ちなみに「改悪改ざん」を主張されていますが、その点も認識が誤っています。

質問 [周方向総応力の　求め方。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/74846/%e5%91%a8%e6%96%b9%e5%90%91%e7%b7%8f%e5%bf%9c%e5%8a%9b%e3%81%ae-%e6%b1%82%e3%82%81%e6%96%b9) において私は編集を行いましたが、あくまであなたの質問に対して派生させたものを新たに投稿したに過ぎません。
あなたの最初の投稿は何ら変更されることなく履歴に残されています。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/74846/1

また、ご懸念の契約更新も影響しません。タイムラインには、一つ一つの投稿がどのライセンスに承諾したものかも明記されています。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/74846/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries

既に利用規約に同意されご認識されていると思いますが、現在はCC BY-SA 4.0となっています。これが例えば私の一番古い投稿ですと

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/2358/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries

となっていて、CC BY-SA 3.0に従い投稿されていることが確認できます。

Comment: 少なくとも、

著作者人格権を、
規約　等で、
移譲しようとする　時点で、
法に　反していますし、

不可能な　事ですので、
無効です。
"

又、

独占的な　地位乱用でも、
ありますよね？
"

更に、

「法曹に　確認を、
取ってある、」
とも　お示ししましたよね？
"

何だか、

とてもヽ　繰り返しばかりですし、
コンブライアンスに対しても、
著作権に対しても、
貴方のような　方までが…

お立場を　反映しての、
事も　あるのでしょうが、

残念に　感じて、
しまいます。

Comment: 更に、改悪は　容認し得ませんよね。

Comment: 一応ですが、

関連項として　確認させて、
頂けますか？
"

勿論、

聞くまでもない　事ながら、

・施工前に　遡った、
　規約適応、
・優越的地位を　背景とした、
　契約更新の　敢行、
等。
"

何れも、

私も、此方サイドも、
共に、

「違法だ、」
との　認識で、
構いませんよね？