# 代行投稿に付いて　方針を　伺わせてください、

Tags: 討議

前提として、

此方での　第1意は、
質問者様困窮の　救済と、=>　有益な　情報収集と、
私は　感じています。
"

其処で、

お伺いさせて　ください。
"

任意な、

其の　時点において、
誰彼に　寄らず、
自身が　解答投稿が、
適わない　場合、

質問者様救済を　=>　有益な情報収集を、
第1意として、
代行による　解答開示を、
求めても、

構わない　ものでしょうか？

Comment: 「代行による　解答開示」とは何ですか？日本語でコミュニティの多くの人に伝わるように書いてください。目的・実現したいことが本当に分かりません。

Comment: 恐らく [別の投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3529) が "クローズ" されたことで回答が付けられない状態のことを指しているのかと思われますが、主に「投稿内容を勝手に書き換えられる」ことについての話題に見えるので "重複" として一旦クローズしました。 / 重複先の投稿とは別の問題と考えるのであれば、[既存の討議](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1630) との違いを強調するように [元の投稿を編集](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3529/edit) してみてください。 / コミュニティユーザーがあなたの投稿を編集したのは、あくまで "改善" を目的としたものですが、あなたが "改悪/改ざん" と思われるのであればその具体的な情報を記してください。

Comment: cubick様、

ご質問　有難うございます。

1/2

〉クローズ" されたことで回答が付けられない状態

いいえ、

左様では　ありませんよ。
"

誰であろうと、

第三者の　意図でも、
では　なくても、

評価次第では　解答投稿が、
今後とも　できなくなる、
事が　起こり得る、
かと　思います。
"

しかし、

そうした　ものでも、
有益な　認知を、
持つ　場合も、
勿論　あります。
" 

例示します。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/10436

ですが。
"

此方、

質問者様　ご自身が、
素因数最小値を　得られる、
前提とすれば。

Comment: 2/2

仮に、

最大値を　Nと、
検証対象値を　Iと、
其の　素因数最小値を、
Jと、
おく　時、

j+I/(LOG ₁₀ N+1)
此を　全てに対して、
求め、
単純に　ソートし、
"

其の後、

小数点以下より　元値を、
復元すれば、
いとも　簡単な、
処理で、

質問者様の　救済が、
適います。
"

ソフトウエアとは、

アルゴリズムだけではなく、
データセットとの　両輪運用こそが、
大切か、
と　思いますの。
"

ですので、

こうした　方向性も、
大切か、

と　考えています。
"

さて、

しかしながら、
討議を　立てさせて、
頂いた　時点では。

私は　回答を、
投じ得ませんでした。
"

飜れば、

重ねますが、
「今　私が、
此の場だけに　限定して、
発生する　もの、」

でも、
此は　ないでしょう。
"

なれば、

其の　情報共有には、
「価値が　あるのかな？」
と、
感じている　次第です、

如何でしょう。

Comment: htb様、

ご質問　有難うございます。
"

早速ですが、

〉目的・実現したいこと

共に、

記載させて　頂いた、
通り、

解決策提示による、
質問者様の　救済です。
"

如何でしょう、

此方で　ご疑念を、
埋めるには　適いましたでしょうか、

適って　いたならば、
幸いなのですが。

Comment: 説明を読んでも「代行による　解答開示」が何を意味しているのか理解できませんでした。加えて「質問者様救済」も具体性がなく目的・実現したいことがわかりませんでした（精神論のようにも見受けられます）。第三者に分かるように説明する必要があると考えます。

Comment: 質問者が第一位かどうか。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto

Comment: えーっと、

更に　前段として、
認識確認させてください。
"

Q&Aサイトとは、

質問者と　回答者の、
双方が　存在して、
始めて　成り立ち。
"

又、

回答者は　質問への、
回答、
詰まり　問題解消意思が、
あってこそ　なり立つ。
"

結局は、

何方にしろ、
質問者急難の、
解消こそが、

大半の　意義で、
第一意だ。
"

此、

違うのでしょうか？
"

他方、

情報への　ルートが、
自己責任外で　絶たれる、
質問者において。
"

其の、

抱えさせられた　不遇とは、
唯の　いい迷惑な、
だけでは　ないのでしょうか？
"

未だ、

幾ばくも　経たぬ、
内ながら、

質問者への　蔑ろ感がら
随所に　見受けられるのですが、

何故でしょうか？

Comment: ここでは質問者、回答者共にあくまで対等な立場であり、"お客様とカスタマーサポート" ではありません。困っている人 (質問者) がいれば周りは可能な限り手助けの努力をしますが、それと同じ様に **質問者自身** も周りの人間に対して "手助けしやすいよう" に気配りの努力が求められますので、[行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct) も今一度参照してください。 / 現時点ではあなたの文章から "質問の意図" を読み取るのが困難なため、読みやすい文章での投稿の努力をしてもらわない限り、周りからの助けも得られません。(手助けは一方的なものではなく、お互いの支え合いで初めて成り立ちます)

Comment: 「蔑ろ、」
という、
下位な　立場が、

貴方方と　対等に、
いるためには、

貴方方外には　必要なのですか？

Comment: 私の　意図とは、
質問文中に　記した、
通りの、

一義のみです。
"

其れは、

質問者様が　誰であろうとも、
其の　方の、
責任外理由により、

有用情報から　遮断されるような、
機会を、
唯　少しだろうと、
減らす　事です。
"

何度も、

申してます　通り、
他意は　ありません、
"

今世にも、

清廉潔白な　存在も、
いるのですがね。
"

いやはや、

何か　勘ぐられたのですか？
"

余談ながら、

酒でも　汲み交わせば、
ご理解も　して頂けると、
思うのですがね、

残念ですね。

Comment: 逆に　伺いますね、
何処に　読み難さを、
感じると　思われますか？
"

いやはや、

「質問者の　ためのみを、
考え、
回答者様と　解決案を、
少しでも　多く、
繋げたい、

其のために　回答代行を、
模索したい、」

他意が　ないと、
すれば、

此以上ない、
端的な　文章だ、

と　思うのですよ。
"

ですので、

読み難いとは、
「何処か、」「何か、」
を、

お示し　頂けますか？

Comment: その人が回答ができない理由によると思いますが、どういった理由で回答ができないとお考えですか？

Comment: 有難うございます。
"

其の点ですが、

今回の　話しの、
発起点は、
確かに　私です。
"

が、

本案件では　其れを、
任意他者にも　水平展開し、

「誰にでも　起こる、
話し、」
と、
捉えた　ものです。
"

ですので、

其の　発言阻害理由は、
未来の　話しも、
含まれます。


此の事は、

既に　質問文面内でも、

〉誰彼に　寄らず、
〉自身が　解答投稿が、
〉適わない　場合、
と、

触れさせて　頂けているか、
と　思います。
"

又、

「システムに　詳しくなく、
網羅し兼ねている　故、
判らない、」
そうした　点も、

如何せん　私には、
あります。
"

ですので、

申し訳ないのですが、
相まって、
其れは　私では、
お答えし兼ねます。
"

尚、

書いてある　事を、
読まず、
「判らない、」
と、

もし　連呼されている、
ならば、
"

其れは、

「とても　残念な、
事、」
との　感覚を、
何ともはや　禁じ得ません。

Comment: 他方、

詰問者の　身に、
立てば、
回答者発言阻害理由は　自責範囲外です。
"

いい変えれば、

回答者にとって　其れは、
「関係ない　話し、」
かと　思います。
"

此の事は、

質問文面内でも、
〉質問者様救済を　第1意として、
と、
又　先筆でも、

双方で　既に、
「触れさせて　頂いている、」
かと　思います。
"

無論、

本案件の　主人公は、
私でも、各他回答者様でも、
なく、
各質問者様方であり。
"

勿論、

此の　方々の、
救済が　第一義です。


ですので、

其の　ご質問は、
「根本的に　論点外、」
と　思えます。
"

正直

包み隠さず　申させて、
頂けるなら、

何故「私の　話、」
と、
規定されてし　まわれるのか、

何故　論点外に、
拘られるのか、

何故　文面を、
お読みに　なられいのか、

一向に　腑に、
落ちません、

如何でしょうか？

Comment: 記載を　一部、変えました。

Answer (score 4):

スタック・オーバーフローでは、特定のユーザーによる回答の投稿がシステムによってブロックされる場合があります。このようにシステムによって投稿ができない状態になっていた場合、そのユーザーが他のユーザーにお願いして回答を投稿してもらうことは **できません**。

回答の投稿ができなくなった場合、新しい回答を投稿しようとすることは一旦控え、まずは既存の回答が改善できないかお試しください。回答が改善され、投稿ブロックの原因が消えるなどすると、再び回答が投稿できるようになります。

より詳しくは以下のヘルプを参照してください：[私のアカウントからの回答が受け付けられなくなったのはなぜですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans)

Comment: nekketsuuu様、

ご答申開示　有難うございます。
"

質問します、

此方での　第一意は、
「質問者様の　救済、」
で　あってますか？
"

又、

此に対し、
反目する　ものは、
ありますか？

Comment: すいません、ご質問の意味がよく分かりませんでした……。

Comment: あぁ　いえいえ、　そんな滅相も　ありませんよ。

Comment: nekketsuuu様、

別途の　質問を、
させて　頂きます。
"

〉誰彼に　寄らず、

此の　様に、
討議請求文面内には、
記載がある　ものと、
思います。
"

しかるに、

何故、
「私(nouble)の　話、」
と　限定されたのか、

お教え　願えませんか？

Comment: 単に、スタック・オーバーフローでは部分回答が許されているというだけですね。

Comment: 済みません、

先にも　触れさせて、
頂いた　通り、
質問者視点ですので、

此に　照らして、
どういう　ご意志での、
ご発言か　解りませんし、

元より　先質問の、
解答にも　なってませんよね？

何故　そう、
書かれたのか？
解説　願えませんか？
"

其れと、

確認なのですが、
皆様に　おいても、

自身に　起こった、
事を　教訓として、

他者被害を　減らそうという、
認識とか、ご意志とかは、

当然に　持たれている、
普遍な　感覚ですよね？
"

私は、

其れはまあ　確かに、
正直　私も、
救済されれば　御の字では、
ありますが。
"

まあ、

こんな　事も、
ままある　事ですし、

最悪は　私は、
救済されなくても
まあねー　て、

所です。
"

しかし、

理不尽な　訳ですから、
理不尽は　へし折るまで、
抗議は　し続けますがね。

Comment: 2/3

だからといって、

こんな事が　今後も、
続いても　いいかと、
いえば、

其れは　やはり、
Noで、

私の　経験が、
生かされないのは、

此の　期に、
改まらないのは、

「何ともはや、」と　感じるのですよ。
"

変えられれば、

解答投稿が　増える、
訳ですから、
質問者満足度も　増えるだろうし、

引いては　当該サイト利用も、
盛んに　向かうだろうし、

いいと　思うのですよ？
"

無論、

質問者様が　より、
優れた　解に、
ありつける　方が、

此の　サイト的にも、
有益ですよね？

違いますか？
"

何故、

再発防止提言と　理解されないのか、
全く　解らないのですが、

何故ですか？

Comment: 3/3

もう一点、

書かれているのに　読まず、
解らないと　示すのは、
何故ですか？
"

又、

其の　場合の、
責任は、

読まない　方に、
ないですか？
"

一般的には、

書いてあるのに　読まず、
解らならいと　発する、
方に、

非を　当てませんか？
"

少なくとも、

私が　書いた、
文面の　何処かに、
「卑下対象が　ある、」
と　いい得ますか？
"

本当に、

書いたのに　読まれず、
書いてない　ていで、
解らないと　いい続けられる、
私が　悪なのですか？
"

いうまでもなく、

句点と、空白と、改行を、
自身の　好みに、
沿って、

テキストエディター、ワープロ、
等で、
置換して　省けば、
違法ながらも　読めるのですよね？
"

何故、

読もうとすれば、
読める　ものを、
読まないのですか？

Comment: 「第三者に代わりの回答投稿を依頼しても構いませんか？」という質問に対して、「システムによって依頼者が回答投稿をブロックされているのであれば、No です」という部分回答を投稿したまでです。それ以外の場合はどういうシチュエーションを想定なさっているのかよく分からなかったので、とりあえず部分回答で済ませたという経緯です。

Comment: 回答の中に nouble さんの名前が出ているのが私の回答の分かりにくさを生んでいるのかなと思って、少し書き直してみました。回答の趣旨は変わっていません。これでも部分回答になっておりませんでしょうか。

Comment: nekketsuuu様、

コメント改訂　有難うございます。
"

しかし、

相違点は、
〉スタック・オーバーフローでは部分回答が
此処では　ないですか？
"

ご改訂内容は、

討議要請とは　趣旨が、
違いませんか？
"

要請文では、

提出の　時点においては、
一般化した　内容ですし、
質問書救済でしたし、

相異ある　内容と、
なって　いませんか？
"

上記通りに、

先筆によりも　示させても、
頂けて　いましたよね？
"

又もや、

何故　読んでも、
頂けないのですか？

Comment: nouble さん、この内容が回答になっていないのでしたら、私が nouble さんの質問を誤読しているということだと思います。うまく理解できていないようなので、理解するための質問をさせてください。コメントを伺う限り、nouble さんが私の回答についてひっかかっているのは「代理投稿依頼の目的として、質問者の疑問解決に焦点があるかどうか」が判断基準に入っていないことなのかなと考えているのですが、合っていますでしょうか？

Comment: nekketsuuu様、

ご質問　有難うございます。
"

さて、

keitaro_so様の　提示を、
拝見するまでは　そうでしたね。
"

しかし、

視点が　変わった、
今だと　しても、
他　コメント通り、
何方にしろ、

問題提起者が　居てこそ
有用情報、先鋭的発想、
此等が　発起し得るのですから、

「情報を　如何なる、
ものからも、
すくい上げられる　機構が、
求められは　しないか、」

と　いう、
点において、
同じ　帰結でしょうね。
"

ですので、

今でも　論点が、
確認　頂く、
必要が、
あるやも　知れませんね。
"

但し、

謝罪の　意図で、
書かれた　ものと、
お見受けします　故、

紳士淑女LGBTq的に、
真摯に　お受け、
致します。

Answer (score 3):

まず前提として
このコミュニティの使命と目的については
[スタック・オーバーフローのマニフェスト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto)

にある通り、

> コミュニティの支えによって、すべてのプログラミングに関する問題への詳細な解答が整理された状態のライブラリを作ること。

です。質問者の問題を解決することが一番ではなくて、質の良い質問と回答を集めることを主題とおいています。結果的にそれが困っているプログラマを助けることになるかもしれないですが、それが第一ではないです。

そのため、質問者と回答者に両方にほかのQAサイトには求められないの制約や品質を求めています。
[質問にあたって](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
[回答にあたって](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/answering)

ただし、単純に厳しく取り締まるだけでは新規参入者のハードルになってしまうため、
[行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)を設定しより誠実に取り組むように設定されています。

つまりはこのサイトは

**マニュフェストおよび行動規範に同意した方に参加してもらうコミュニティサイトです**

サイトがあってコミュニティが生まれたのではなくコミュニティがあったうえでのサイトができています。

このマニュフェストに賛同いただけない方は別のQAサイトを利用してもらうほかございません。
もちろんmetaでマニフェストに対する異議や討議は受け付けますのでご気軽に投稿してください。
※ただし、個人的にはこのコミュニティの根幹になるため、おおきな方向転換は難しいと思います。

そのうえで回答させていただくと、
代理の投稿の是非については
サイト（＝コミュニティ）が禁止していることについては残念ながらコミュニティの運営において行われていることになります。nekketsuuu♦様の回答通りコミュニティの規則にのっとって対応をお願いします。

それ以外の例えば、
何らかのハンディキャップがあり、アカウント作成および投稿がかなわない場合や
スタックオーバーフローを知らない回答を知っている会社の同僚の代わりに投稿するは基本的にＯＫかと思います。また自分が所属している組織やプロジェクトの代表として回答することももちろんありです。
その場合は信用度は代行投稿した人に加算してしまいます。きちんと回答者代行者で意思疎通をし、お互いに行き違いのないよう事前に会話でお話をしておきましょう。

Comment: 最後の段落について補足すると、システムから一時的な制限(ブロック)を受けている場合は単一のアカウントに対してではなく、接続元のネットワークも考慮した制限がかかる場合があります。これは "制限を回避する" 目的で複数アカウントの作成を抑止するためだと思われます。[参考ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/question-limited) / この点も踏まえて、もし会社や学校など組織のネットワークからアクセスしている場合には周りのユーザーにも影響を与えてしまう可能性も考慮した立ち振る舞いが求められます。

Comment: 1/5

keitaro_so様、

ご投稿　有難うございます。
"

〉気を配りましょう

配っていますよね。
"

〉辛抱強くなり、
〉全ての人を温かく
〉受ける時には寛容な態度で
〉親切でフレンドリーな態度を

そうした　対応を、
微塵も　感じません。
"

寧ろ、

敵意しか　感じませんでしたよ。
"

何故ですか？

書いた　事すら、
真面に　読みも、
されませんし、
信じても　貰えません。
"

故、

何故　私が、
一方的に、
此の　様な、
立場に　おかれるか、

示し　頂けば、
頂くほど、

混迷が　深まりました。

Comment: 2/5

私が、

唯１度たりとも、
〉けなす言動や敵意のある言葉
〉個人に対する批評は許されません。
〉偏見は許されません。
〉嫌がらせは許されません。
此等の　内の、
一つでも　犯しましたか？

此の様な　ものを、
被せる　事は、

此等の　何れかに、
あたりませんか？
"

剰え、

投稿を　遮断されたものに、
〉おっと!エラーが発生しました!
とは、
内心を　かき乱しませんか？

スタックオーバフローとして
上内容の　一つたりともに、
反してないと　いい得ますか？
"

此、

紳士的な　反論を、
示し、
停止を　求め、
不快を　述べても。
"

其れは、

基本的人権たる、
抗議権の　内では、
ありませんか？
"

此の　様な、
ものを、
私に　示されさる、
事は、

とても　不愉快です、
一部投稿撤回を　求めても、
構いませんか？

Comment: 3/5

〉マニュフェストおよび行動規範に同意

其れは、

「私か　違反者だ、」
との　摘発で、
詰まりは　冒涜に、
値しませんか？

不愉快ですよ。


〉サイトがあっ〈割愛〉きています。

大筋で　同意します、

卵か、鶏かの、
論点は、
残る　ものと、
思いますが。
"

〉マニュフェストに賛同いただけない

解りました、

では　私も、
論を　改めましょう、

質問者救済第一義ではなく、
優良情報集積とでも　いうか、
其の　様な、
事ですね？
"

では、

改めたのですから、
新たに　沿って、
お話しを　しませんか？

私の　例示には、
情報優位性が　認められませんか？
"

恐らく、

ソフトウエア工学には、
ある程度なりとも、
精通されて　いますよね？
"

アルゴリズム評価と　しても、
今後の　並列化コンピューティング展開的にも、
優位性が　認められませんか？

未来投稿者にも　優位性は、
認め得ませんか？

Comment: 4/5

アルゴリズムとして　コスト？が、
nの　累乗化する、
ものですか？

有用な　上質情報では、
ないのですか？
"

回答封鎖者より、

其の　マニュフェストに、
沿った　回答が、

此の　例示のように、
示された　場合、

貴方方自身が　マニュフェストに、
背きますか？

回答封鎖者からの　提案を、
汲み取る　仕組みは、

其の　マニュフェストに、
照らして　不要ですか？
"

〉信用度は代行投稿した人に加算してしまいます。

其れ等より、

私個人と　しましては、
質問者の　救済と、
上質情報の　集積の、
方が　魅力的ですので、

意にも　関しません。
"

まぁ、

貰えないのも、
未来　誰かは、
抗議するでしょうし、
しゃくでも　ありますがね。
"

しかし、

少なくとも　今、
誰かの　良質情報で、
社会が、個人が、
救われ　改善されるなら、
上々です。
"

私は、

希有かも　知れませんが、
社会欲というか、

そうした　ものの、
方が、

圧倒的に　個人的欲求より、
上回るのです。

Comment: 5/5

〉お互いに行き違いのないよう事前に会話で

一義の　異を、
挟む　余地もなく、
賛同　致します。


では、

其処で　提案を、
致します。


私では、

先の　文面内容中の、
何処の　質が、
悪いのか、
全く　解りません。


其処で、

いきなり　変えて、
頂くのではなく、

ご提案、ご指摘を、
募りたく　思います、

如何でしょうか？


後記、

詰問者発起スレッドや、
投稿文が　読まれない、
其の　他での、
投稿者蔑ろぶりには、

なんとも　閉口を、
感じて　しまいます。


勿論、

コメント欄や、
其の　他でも、
抗議権は　基本的人権内なので
封殺は　し得ないでしょう。


しかしながら、

一方で　現状が、
是とも　思えません。


如何でしょうか、

改善は　不要でしょうか？

Comment: cubick様、

補足　有り難うございます、
"

しかしながら、

其れ　ゲス向けの、
説明対応では？
"

少なくとも、

今　私は、
そんな　事を、
した　覚えは、
ありません。
"

些かも、

今回　気分を、
害しましたよ？

Comment: この質問はあくまで、投稿がかなわない人が代行投稿をしてよいかという質問のため、nouble様が停止に至った経緯の説明ではないことはご了承ください。停止に対する抗議や査定の公開要求であるならばその主旨の質問をしてください。

Comment: 私の回答は質問者様に対してである一方でこのサイトを訪れた人または既に参加している人たち向けの回答でもあります。（ライブラリの役割です）そのため私の回答をもとにnouble様に限らず、nouble様とやり取りした方々すべての人に今一度ご自身の振る舞いを自問自答していただけることを切に願いを込めて一部撤回はいたしません。

Comment: 私もnobule様とコメントでいくつかやり取りして、考えや利他的言説をもとにされていることは良く理解しているつもりです。なので停止に至ってしまったのは残念です。より良い方向に行くことを望んでいます。

Comment: ポイントとしては2つですかね。nouble様の文体が質が悪いと判断されるのはなぜか？なぜアカウントの制限になってしまったか？

Comment: あとはアカウント制限時のエラーメッセージがラフすぎる。これは別途議題に挙げてもいいかもしれないですね。

Comment: 何故、

ご提案は　ないのでしょうか？
抑も「提案点がない、」
と　理解して、
構わないのでしょうか？

Comment: 「質が悪いと判断されるのはなぜか？」の質問に対する提案のことを指すのであれば、メタも一問一答形式になるので新しい議題は新しい質問を起こす必要があります。コメントでの回答は控えさせていただきます。

Comment: keitaro様、
"
投稿　有難うございます。
"
"
解りました、
"
と　いう事は、
別討議を　立てて、
"
其方で　改善案を、
募れば　いいと、
いう　訳ですね。

Comment: 今、
"
ご定案を　真摯に、
受け止め、
実行に　移そうとした、
所、
権限がなく　できませんでした。
"
"
ですので、
"
keitaro_so様の　ご誠意に、
此方としても　答えたくは、
あるのですが。
"
"
やはり、
"
現状打破を　鑑みるに、
合意を　図った、
条件内での　救済特例措置を、
願うか、
"
私の　内のみでは、
代行投稿の　提案以外を、
提案するか、
"
其れ等の　外はなく。
" 
"
故、
"
此が　必要と、
帰結せざるを　得ませんでした、
"
誠に　残念です。
"
"
元より、
"
此は　状況要員で、
私では　どうにも、
できない、

責任外の　事ですので、
申し訳ないのですが。
"
"
あしからず、
"
ご了承、ご容赦、
頂ければ　幸いです。
"
"
さて、
"
と　申していても、
始まりませんので、
"
何かしらの、
ご提案、ご措置を、
頂ければと　思います、
"
如何でしょうか。

Comment: それは残念です。私が代わりに投稿してもと思いましたが、そうしたところできっとnouble様はコメントや回答ができない状態と見受けれらますので結果的に欠席裁判みたいな形になってしまいそうなので控えさせていただきます。一緒に討議してより良い方向に迎えるとよいのですが

Comment: keitaro_so様　有難うございます。
"
〉nouble様は、
〉コメントや　回答が、
〉できない　状態と、
〉見受けれらますので、
〉結果的に　欠席裁判みたいな、
〉形になって、
"
コメントが　必要な、
場合に、
意見を　求めて、
頂けるなら、
"
今回限定では、
全く　構いません。
"
"
寧ろ、
"
お願いしたく　思います。
"
"
しかし、
"
本件要点は、
システムに　組み込む、
事です。
"
ご検討　頂けませんか？

Comment: 何故　提案を、頂けないのですか？

Comment: こういっては、
"
失礼かとも　思いますが、
敢えても　マニフェストを、
提示された　上で、
"
其の　ご対応を、
取られる　事に。
"
"
私としては、
"
如何ともせず　疑問を、
禁じ得ませんが、
"
何故　そうした、
態度に　留まられるのですか？
"
"
解りません、
"
敢えても　提示なされた、
マニフェスト遵守は、
如何　なされましたか？

Comment: コメントが滞って失礼しました。私自身代行投稿はだめだと言っている立場ですので、代行依頼をされてしまうと投稿は憚られます。このコメントのやり取りを読んでもしくはクローズされたりマイナス投票された質問を見て、疑問に思った方がメタに投稿してくれることを期待していましたが、特に投稿はなさそうですね。

Comment: あとはモデレーターにお願いするぐらいかな。。