# 校正提案を　伺いたく、思います。

Tags: 討議

例示文面としては、

[代行投稿に付いて　方針を　伺わせてください、](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3532/%e4%bb%a3%e8%a1%8c%e6%8a%95%e7%a8%bf%e3%81%ab%e4%bb%98%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6-%e6%96%b9%e9%87%9d%e3%82%92-%e4%bc%ba%e3%82%8f%e3%81%9b%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a0%e3%81%95%e3%81%84)
此方ですが。
"

ようやくと、

質問が　立てられるように、
なましたので、

keitaro_so様　ご提示を、
受け、
》私の　文体に対する、
》校正案、

此方を　求めたく、
思います.

keitaro_so様　有難うございます。
"

そして、

其の　折には、
科学的エビデンス、他、
等に　基づき、

是非　以下を、
守りつつ、
お示し　頂く、
事と、

させては　頂けないでしょうか？
"

ではでは、

・　句点を　文事内に、
　　埋もれさせない、

・　句点は　文節区切り位置のみ、
　　と　する、

・　単語区切りを　意味区切りとして、
　　何処で　切れるかを、
　　明確に　表す、

・　読点ばかりを　多用せず、
　　他の　区切り方を、
　　持ちい、
　　読点乱用を　避ける、

・　文節は　7〜10単語以内で、
　　何らかを　持って、
　　明確に　境を、
　　示す、

・　文節間流れ、文節テーマ、
　　等の、
　　明示の　ため、

＿　文節タイトルを　文節本体から、
　　切り離し、
　　何らかによって　明示的に
　　表す、

・　一行は　概ね、
　　20文字以内、2単語以内、

・　行末には　解り易く、
　　なるように、
　　毎行　読点を、
　　付ける、

・　箇条書き各項は、

＿　1単語の　時は、
　　読点で　区切り、
　　一行に　出来るだけ、
　　併記、

＿　複数副単語の　セット時は、
　　修飾関係明示の　ために、
　　行を　分け、
　　列記する、

＿　更に、
　　列記項、併記項は、
　　できるなら　各々に、
　　固める、

・　修飾関係にある　単語間には、
　　極力　他単語を、
　　挟まず　整理する、

＿　又　修飾関係を、
　　クロスさせず、
　　スパゲッティー化を　防ぐ、

・　「デファクトスタンドー≠ベスト」
　　である　事を、
　　意識して　闊達に、
　　記載を　する、

・　一部正式記載法に　習い、
　　こうじつ追記用に　右側に、
　　空白を　多く、
　　設ける。
"

如何でしょう、

記載ルール欠落項も　あるやも、
知れませんが、

其れは　追々と、
させて　頂きつつも、

ご提案　頂けますか？

Comment: ちなみに「科学的エビデンス等を用いて提案してほしい」とありますが、この文章が読みやすく理解しやすいという科学的エビデンス等はありますか？

Comment: この「校正提案」の対象は nouble さんの文章に対して、ということですか？

Comment: cubick様、
"
ご質問　有難うございます。
"
"
しかし、
"
もしかしたら　貴方は、
マニュフェスト違反を　犯されては、
いないでしょうか？
"
"
何故なら、
"
質問文冒頭に、
》例示文面としては、
とあり、
此をすら　読まなかった、
事が、
明白だからです。
"
"
如何なのでしょう、
"
質問文冒頭記載すら　読まず、
どのような　努力を、
御身内に　課されたかが、
気になります。

Comment: keitaro_so様、 
"
ご質問　有難うございます。 
"
"
勿論ですよ、
"
嘘　等、
申しませんし。
"
"
無論、
"
誰に　取っても、
》其の方自身が　知らなければ、
"
》其の　対象が、
》存在し得ない、
なんて、
"
事象の　在り方も、
存在しませんよね？
"
"
其れとも、
"
私は　嘘吐き呼ばわりを、
されて　いるのですか？
"
"
一例ですが、
"
 もう　古くから、
 人間工学上での　定説を
加味した　ものですよ。
"
"
べた書きは確かにディファクトスタンダードですが、
"
"
反面、
"
制約を　受けたが、
故の、
歪まされた　スタンダードで、
"
"
触れるまでもなく、
"
ベストでは　ありませんよ。

Comment: その人間工学上の定説を基にしてどのように文体に反映されているのか教えて下さい。

Comment: あとnouble様はほかのやりとりと合わせて見るに、なぜが悪いほうに考えすぎている気がします。特にnouble様を攻撃しているととらえがちのようですね。私は全く嘘だと思っていませんし、皮肉でもなんでもなく単純な質問です。まずは質問されたことにシンプルに回答することをお願いしたいです。

Comment: もしかして  ベタがきを 読むことが nouble様は苦手 ですか？、 nouble様は ベタがきも読み書きできる が あえてこの文体に していると 私は 思っていました、 その場合 回答を転換する 必要がある と 私は感じます

Comment: keitaro_so様、
"
ご質問　有り難うございます、
対応が　遅れ、
申し訳ない。
"
"
以前、
"
別答申を　示したやも、
知れませんが、
改めて　お答えします。
"
"
〉 ベタがきも読み書きできる
"
できます、
"
寧ろ　初稿は、
べた書きな　時が、
ある位です。
"
"
〉 あえてこの文体に している
"
しています、
"
本来あるべき、
文体に　整える、
事は　当たり前です。
"
"
〉回答を転換する 必要がある
"
済みません、
"
此の　場で、
転換と　用いられていますが、
どの様な　意図でしょう？
"
"
と、
"
聞いて　おきながら、
なんなのだすか、
" 
もし　質問主題外の、
事ならば、
別討議を　お立てください。

Answer (score 4):

私自身文芸出身ではなく完全に理系専攻で、残念ながら国語の理解や文の理解についての論文は非常に疎いもので、私が考える読みやすい文章に科学的エビデンスも何もないです。

ただ我々は日本語の話者もしくは日本語の習得者であり、それの知識習得のためには、小学校からの国語教育がベースになっており、そのため文科省が定める日本語教育に沿った文章を記述すれば、大勢の人に読みやすくまた理解しやすい文章が書けると思っています。

もちろん、国語教育を受けずに日本語を習得された方や、文科省が定める日本語教育に異議を唱える方がいらっしゃることも事実です。おっしゃる通り「デファクトスタンダード≠ベスト」です。しかしながら「私が考えるベスト≠あなたが考えるベスト」でもあります。私は国語教育で学んだ文章の作り方がわかりやすいと思っているだけです。偶然それがデファクトスタンダードだっただけです。

また文科省の小委員会が出している『[「公用文作成の要領」の見直し](https://www.bunka.go.jp/seisaku/bunkashingikai/kokugo/kokugo/kokugo_72/pdf/r1422554_04.pdf)』や『[公用文改善の趣旨徹底について](https://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/sisaku/joho/joho/kijun/sanko/koyobun/pdf/yoryo_ver02.pdf)』も参考にするとより良いかなと思います。
公用文は広く国民に適切に理解をしてもらうためにある程度ルールや書き方のコツがあるようで、
そのノウハウはこのスタックオーバーフローでも活用できると思います。

そのうえで回答させていただくと、
（１）句読点の使い方
質問に挙げられている句読点のルール自体に現状の国語教育にあまり沿った書き方ではないでしょう。[区切り符号の使い方](https://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/sisaku/joho/joho/kijun/sanko/pdf/kugiri.pdf)を参考にしてみてください。読点ばっかり多用されると、文がつながっているという誤解が生まれてしまいます。

（２）修飾被修飾で文節を区切る
また修飾を明確にするために文節で区切るという方法もあまり一般的ではなく、修飾語の関係は
・複数の意味になるような修飾－被修飾の関係を避ける
・係る語とそれを受ける語は近くに置く
だけで文節を区切ってまで表示する必要はないという認識です。

（３）漢字や単語やひらがな
常用漢字でない文字や少し古めの音読文字を多用する癖がありそうですが、
・特殊なことばを用いたり，かたくるしいことばを用いることをやめて，日常一般に使われているやさしいことばを用いる。
・常用漢字表にある漢字であっても、文書の性格や対象となる読み手に応じて、平仮名で表記したり、読み仮名を用いたりする
と先に示したドキュメントにも記述がありますので、一般の方が日常的につかわない単語を直してもらう。ひらがなに直してもらうだけ読みやすくなると思います。

・日常的に使わない単語
此方→こちら
困窮→困りごと
救済→助けること
誰彼に寄らず→どんな人であっても
第1意→第一の目的
適わない→できない

・ひらがなに直す
其処で→そこで

（４）空白の必要性
文章の空白についてはサイトの特性上編集追記の履歴が確認できます。
紙に記述するような直すのが大変である特性ではないものなので
あまり気にする必要はないかなと思います。

（５）単語の一貫性
「解答」の「投稿」なのか「開示」なのかきちんと文中は言葉を合わせたほうがいいでしょう。

（６）主語述語をきちんと書く
あとは主語と述語を明確にして
「誰が解答の投稿を求めるのか？」→ここだと「自分で解答の投稿ができない人」ですね。

（６）指示語の明確化
指示語も明確にするとより伝わりやすいと思います。
「此方」→こちらのサイト、このスタックオーバーフロー、
「其処で」→それを踏まえて、その前提を元に考えると

（７）ちょっとおまけ（ここはより個人的な意見なので分かれそう）
また元の文章は「解答の投稿を求める」とありますが、
「解答の投稿を求める」だと「要求する」感じになってしまうので「依頼する」「お願いする」のほうがよりいいかなと思います。

それを踏まえて元の文章を直すと

「こちらのサイトでの第一の目的は、
有益な情報収集（追記前「質問者様の困りごとを助けること」）と、私は感じています。

その前提を踏まえてお伺いさせてください。

任意なその時点で、どんな人であっても、自分自身が解答の投稿ができない場合、

（追記前「質問者様の困りごとを助けること」）有益な情報収集を第一の目的として、その投稿できない人が代行の人に解答の投稿をお願いしても構わないものでしょうか？」

Comment: お話が長引いていたため、この会話をチャットに移動しました。こちらで議論いただければと思います： https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123667/discussion-on-answer-by-keitaro-so-