# スタックオーバーフローの投稿における著作者人格権の主張について

Tags: 討議

関連議題
[勝手に質問を編集されるのを禁止するオプションが欲しい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1630/)
[ネコ語の語尾を編集して「ですます体」にするのは問題ないか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1649/)
[文体違法改悪改ざんに付いて。](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3529/)

恥ずかしながら著作者人格権というものを最近知り、いくつか書籍を参考に理解を進めましたが、
スタックオーバーフローにおける著作者人格権の扱いが不十分ではないかという疑念が生まれました。

> 著作者人格権
> とは著作権の一部であり、著作物の創作者である著作者が精神的に傷つけられないよう保護する権利の総称である。美術・文芸・楽曲・映像といった著作物には、著作者の思想や感情が色濃く反映されているため、第三者による著作物の利用態様によっては著作者の人格的利益を侵害する恐れがある

> 著作権法第59条
> 著作者人格権は、著作者の一身に専属し、譲渡することができない。

質問や回答の著作者人格権は守られるべきであり、今後もその権利を脅かすことはできません。
しかしながら、このコミュニティにおいて著作者人格権を主張されて、質問の改変や回答の改変の禁止をされてしまうとコミュニティの運営に支障が生まれてしまいます。

スタックオーバーフローにおける投稿の著作者人格権を主張された場合の対応はどうしたらよいですか？

私自身はコミュニティの意義や使命については賛同しております。
いまの編集や改変を許容した形かつ著作者人格権を脅かさない形で運営をしていくことが大事だと思っています。
なのでこのコミュニティを今のまま存続していく前提で討議は進めたいと思っています。

いくつかの回答で感じましたが、
著作権と著作者人格権の違いがやはり難しいですね。
https://www.cric.or.jp/qa/hajime/hajime2.html

日本の法律では
著作権の中に二つ権利があって
・著作人格権
・著作権（財産権）
と呼ばれるものがあり、日本の法律上、譲渡できない権利があるので、このSOの規約で制限をしているのは「・著作権（財産権）」がメインと私は考えています。

Comment: https://creativecommons.jp/faq/#b14 と https://creativecommons.jp/faq/#b15 が関係ありそう、というリンクのシェアっす

Comment: こちらも併せて読んでみてください。[著作権法の守備範囲](https://system.jpaa.or.jp/patents_files_old/201311/jpaapatent201311_137-155.pdf)

Comment: 著作者人格権の不行使条項に関連しそうな気がします。今回の場合は条項自体の有効性というよりも、不行使の合意の効力のような議題になりそうです。

Comment: 著作権の二つの権利について、SO の規約上ユーザの投稿したコンテンツには CC-BY-SA 4.0 が付与されますが、このライセンスでは著作人格権について「著作者人格権は～可能な限り～そのような権利を放棄し、および／または主張しないことに同意します[\[*引用元\]](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode.ja#s2b)」と書かれていることから、前者も事実上制限されているといえるのではないでしょうか？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

個人的には、仮にこのサイトへの投稿が「著作物」ではないとすると、任意の海賊版サイトを立ち上げて、そこに CC-by-SA の制約をうけずに、好きに転載することに対して、それは問題は何もない、ということになってしまいそうです。

一応、自分が CC-by-SA と著作者人格権について調べた内容を共有しておきますと、著作者人格権により、特に日本の法律では、これは破棄できないもの、というふうになっている模様です。特に、この Q&A にそれが見てとれます。( https://creativecommons.jp/faq/#b15 )

これに対して CC-by-SA はどう対応しているかというと、

> 1. 同一性保持の権利のような著作者人格権は、本パブリック・ライセンスのもとではライセンスされません。パブリシティ権、プライバシー権、および／または他の類似した人格権も同様です。ただし、可能なかぎり、許諾者は、あなたがライセンスされた権利を行使するために必要とされる範囲内で、また、その範囲内でのみ、許諾者の保持する、いかなるそのような権利を放棄し、および／または主張しないことに同意します。

https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode.ja

というのが CC-by-SA のライセンス条項であり、CC-by-SA投稿の作成者は、「可能な限り著作者人格権は主張しないこと」に同意している、と言えそうです。可能なかぎり、なので「どうしても無理なんだ!」という主張は可能そうではありますが。。。

―

ただ、その、「CC-by-SA で公開することによる著作者人格権にかかる制限は、日本国においてはどこまでが妥当なのか」というおそらく法律の専門家に聞かなければならないことについて議論するよりかは、個人的には、以下のように議論を進めていく方が良いのではないか、と思います:

> スタック・オーバーフローは「コラボレーションによってナレッジを共有していくプラットフォーム」であり、それにそぐわない投稿は民意によって公開を差し止めることなど(e.g. コミュニティボットや削除投票、 DownVote)ができるプラットフォームである

そして、自分はスタック・オーバーフローは、(i)プログラマーのための知識集約 (ii) Be Nice を柱とするコミュニティであると捉えていて、このふたつのうちどちらがかけてもスタック・オーバーフローたりえないな、とは思います。であるならば、このサイトにはそういうプラグマティックな側面があり、もちろん、かといって言葉狩りみたいなものはおそらく誰も望んでいないですが、しかし、知識の集約のために次第に文体が整理されていくことは不可避であって、それがどうしても同意できないならば、おそらく別のコミュニティに参加していただく方が良い、ということになるのかな、と思います。

Comment: 現行法とSO規約を照らし合わせて「完全な不行使の合意」が得られないとすると主権者の主張は通さざる得ないでしょうね。そのうえで文体整理の意義と目的を誠実に説明するしかないのかもしれないですね。

Comment: 規約が著作者人格権に違反しているかどうか、著作者人格権の不行使条項の強制力については見解が分かれそうなところです。これ以上はStackExchangeチームに見解を聞くほかないかなと思います。そのうえでコミュニティとしては、知識集約ライブラリのための編集は許容されるべきであり、そういったコミュニティであることでどうにか折り合いをつけるというこの回答を承認しておきます。

Answer (score 7):

もっとシンプルに「本人が自分の意志で利用規約に同意した」が尊重されると考えています。同意した利用規約に書かれている行為（例えば派生させた成果物が作られ、公開される）が実施されることに何ら問題はないはずです。

仮に著作者人格権と利用規約がコンフリクトしたとして、著作者人格権を優先した場合、単に「利用規約への同意を取り消す」であり、同時に質問や回答も無効となるだけです。「利用規約へ同意せずStack Overflowを利用し続けたい」という主張されたとしても、それは著作者人格権の範囲外となるはずです。

---

引用では伝わらないようなので。

著作者人格権に対しては、各投稿のリビジョン１として保持されています。

- いつでもだれでもリビジョン１を見ることができます（公表権）
- リビジョン１の投稿者名は常に表示されます（氏名表示権）
- リビジョン１の内容が改変されることはありません（同一性保持権）

その上で、投稿と同時に同意した利用規約により、投稿者はStack Overflowに対して投稿内容を派生させること・派生した成果物を公開することを認めます。Stack Overflow上で行われる「編集」とは、この利用規約に基づき（リビジョン１を書き換える行為ではなく）派生させたリビジョン２を作り公開することです。

---

cubickさんが

> 投稿は何時でも誰でも編集できますが、"同一性保持" という視点で言えば投稿の意図を崩さないことが求められます。例えば誰かが「地球の周りを太陽が回っている」と書いていても、断りなく「太陽の周りを地球の周りを待ってる」と書き換えてしまうのは NG です。

と書かれていますが、この書き換えを行った編集者の派生著作物であり、著作者人格権の観点では不法行為ではありません。ただし、Stack Overflowとして有益でない著作物なので、モデレーターや他の編集者によって、ロールバックや新たな編集が行われるというだけです。その際もリビジョン２・リビジョン３の形で、それぞれの著作者人格権は保護されます。

Comment: Yuki Inoue♦さんの回答の通り利用規約では著作権については移譲破棄するものの、著作者人格権については「可能な限り著作者人格権は主張しないこと」程度にしか制約できないという前提ではどうですか？

Comment: 補足として、著作権は移譲破棄しているのではなく、恒久的なCC-by-SAライセンスをスタックオーバーフローに許諾している、という構造だと思ってます。

Comment: 投稿の書き換え (編集) はあくまで「編集」でしかなく、これをもって派生物とは見なさいと思います。GitHub のリポジトリに当てはめてイメージしてみると、パッチを作者宛てに送るか、リポジトリ自体をフォークするか、辺りの違いになるかと。

Comment: @cubick 編集が派生物と見なすか重要な気がします。書き換えられた部分は編集者の著作物であり、残りの部分は原作者の著作物なままであり、全体としては派生物という理解でした。パッチを原作者に送る場合もCLA; Contributor License Agreementsが求められますし。

Answer (score 4):

スタック・オーバーフローは主にQ&Aのナレッジを投稿するサイトです。
一方、著作権や著作人格権というのは主に創作物を対象とした権利であり、ソースコードに関しては対象と言えるでしょうが、当サイトに投稿にあたって権利の問題が懸念されるようであれば (会社のソースコードなどは) "一般化" して投稿するか、投稿を差し控えるかになるはずです。

単なる説明の部分や、句読点や改行の使い方一つ一つまで創作性を見出して権利を主張するのは無理筋な気がするし、そういった個性を披露する場でもありません。(問題解決のやり取りにのみ注力すべき)

投稿は何時でも誰でも編集できますが、"同一性保持" という視点で言えば投稿の意図を崩さないことが求められます。例えば誰かが「地球の周りを太陽が回っている」と書いていても、断りなく「太陽の周りを地球の周りを待ってる」と書き換えてしまうのは NG です。

---

以下は蛇足になるかもしれませんが、句読点や改行、言葉使い等に対する考え方です。

ここでの投稿は質問・回答共に "第三者" に向けての文章なはずで、ナレッジの蓄積という意味では内容もさることながら "誤解なく伝わる読みやすさ" が求められると思っています。

例えば「エラーを吐く」という表現があります。知っている人が "目にすれば" 何を表すかはわかるものですが、検索する時のことを考えると「表示」や「出力」といった表現を使った方が適切と考えます。

**サイト内検索の結果:**

- [エラー 吐く](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%80%80%E5%90%90%E3%81%8F) (129件)
- [エラー 表示](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%80%80%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA) (1,865件)
- [エラー 出力](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%80%80%E5%87%BA%E5%8A%9B) (794件)

英語版においても "r u (are you)" などの略字や 行頭の "I" が大文字じゃない文章をどうする？といった、割と些細な編集に対しての討議がありますが、「読みやすさの改善につながると思うのであれば、あなたが編集してください」という意見が多いようです。

Answer (score 3):

こういうサービスは利用規約で著作権行使に対して制限を課すことが一般的で、[スタック・オーバーフローの利用規約](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service)(日本語版からのリンクもここになっています)においては次の部分が該当すと私は解釈しています:

> ### 5. User Obligations
>
> Please note that any content or information you share publicly is governed by the terms described below in the section titled [“Content Permissions, Restrictions, and Creative Commons Licensing,”](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing) and **you should be aware that once you place content in the public sphere, you willingly give up some rights and control over such content.**

> ### 6. Content Permissions, Restrictions, and Creative Commons Licensing
>
> #### Subscriber Content
>
> You agree that any and all content, including without limitation any and all text, graphics, logos, tools, photographs, images, illustrations, software or source code, audio and video, animations, and product feedback (collectively, “Content”) that you provide to the public Network (collectively, “Subscriber Content”), is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow on a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive basis pursuant to Creative Commons licensing terms ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)), and you grant Stack Overflow the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to access, use, process, copy, distribute, export, display and to commercially exploit such Subscriber Content, (snip)

Comment: 著作権の話ではなくて、あくまで著作者人格権になります。Yuki Inoue♦の回答にあるとおりCC-by-SAですら縛ることができない文言があるのでどうしようかと考えていました。

Comment: すみません、著作権に対してさほど詳しいわけでは無く(かつ英語の理解も十分であるとは考えておらず)、自分の解釈が絶対正しいと確信しているわけではないのですが、私の文章内の著作権とは[著作者人格権を含む広義の著作権](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%91%97%E4%BD%9C%E6%A8%A9#%E8%91%97%E4%BD%9C%E8%80%85%E4%BA%BA%E6%A0%BC%E6%A8%A9)を想定していて、著作者人格権も利用規約によって行使を制限されている、という認識でした。([こちら](https://www.bunka.go.jp/chosakuken/keiyaku_manual/1_1_3.html#Anchor-11481)の注釈にあるように: "著作権は譲渡できますが、著作者人格権は譲渡できません。...利用者に自由に使わせる必要がある場合などは、著作者人格権を行使しない旨を規定する例も見受けられます。")

Answer (score 3):

関連議題を 3 つ挙げられていますが、

1. [勝手に質問を編集されるのを禁止するオプションが欲しい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1630/)
2. [ネコ語の語尾を編集して「ですます体」にするのは問題ないか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1649/)
3. [文体違法改悪改ざんに付いて。](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3529/)

結局のところ、「著作者人格権」という論点が出てきたのは 3 だと思いますので、それについて。

当該の Q&A では、StackOverFlow が、

> 著作者人格権を、 規約　等で、 移譲しようとする　時点で、 法に　反して

いるという主張ですが、まず StackOverFlow が規約で制限しようとしているのは、著作者人格権ではなく著作権です。

なので、CC-by-SA というライセンス自体がこの世に存在することに文句があるというのであれば、CC そのものを相手に喧嘩を売ってもらう必要があります。SO が「著作者人格権を犯している」という前提で、SO の規約にイチャモンをつけること自体が筋違いです。

また、SO が CC-by-SA というライセンスに基いて質問を投稿することを求めていることの是非について、違法性を問うのであれば、世界中の CC-by-SA ライセンスを利用しているサービスも同様に違法性を有していることになります。もちろん、その（CC-by-SA ライセンスを課すること自体が違法である）可能性が完全に無いとは断言できませんが、実際問題として無理筋でしょう。

そもそも SO の規約に違法性が高ければ、訴訟大国である本家アメリカで問題にされ、敗訴し、賠償金を毟り取られて、規約の変更を余儀なくされてそうですが、そんな気配はありませんね。

さらにおそらく、SO が違法である旨のお墨付をいただいた（？）件の弁護士に訴訟を頼んだところで、サイト（StackExchange）の管轄裁判所はニューヨークだと思うので、日本から怒鳴り込んで勝目があるのだろうか。

等々、私なら、この段階でこれ以上気にすることは打ち切りですね。

著作者人格権自体の適用範囲についての議論はあるにせよ、ともかくその論点と StackOverFlow の運用の是非を結び付けることに元から無理筋だと思っています。

Comment: 私自身もSOの規約は法律に違反しているとはおもっていません。Yuki Inoue♦の回答にあるとおりCC-by-SA ですらライセンスできない制約できない、著作者人格権を主張された場合の対応を確認したいと思っています。

Comment: またアメリカ云々のコメントをいただきましたが、そもそもアメリカには著作者人格権に関する明文化された法律がないのかもしれません。そうなると日本人向けのコミュニティですが、法律準拠はアメリカなんですって言えば、逃げれるかな？？[参考](https://www.issj.net/mm/mm0413/mm0413-9-3q.html#:~:text=%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%E3%80%81%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A1%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AB%E3%82%84%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AE%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE,%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88%E3%82%82%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82)

Comment: @keitaro_so *著作者人格権を主張された場合の対応* 基本、そのような主張をされる方というのは、著作権と著作者人格権の区別が曖昧で、SO の規約の狙いもよくわかっていない、誤解に基づく主張でしょうから、「著作者人格権の適用範囲」という、おそらく法律の専門家にとっても微妙な論点についての問題提起として受け止めなくてもいい場合が 99.99% でしょうね。それで残りの 0.01% 部分の場合は、[General Provisions](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#provisions) に従って Courts of the State of New York に出訴していただくなりするしかないと。

Comment: @keitaro_so 著作者人格権というのは、「著作者であれば、自分の著作物に対して王様のような絶対的支配力を持っている」というわけではないでしょう。例えば同一性保持については、著作者 A が「カラスは黒である」と述べたのをあたかも「カラスは白である」と述べているかのように改変するようなことを禁じて、著作者の声望を保護するためのものです。SO は技術ナレッジのサイトですから、その技術的文脈の中で、著作者の声望が保護されれば足り、詩的文学的な表現性の部分まで保護する義務はないはずです。

Comment: 「技術ナレッジのサイト」この部分の理解なんでしょうね。やっぱりSOとしての使命や大事にしていることを理解してもらうことが第一なのかな

Answer (score 2):

特異で強烈な主張をする人が現れると、普段はあまり意識していない基本的な概念も揺らいでしまいますね。

質問者さんも同意されているように、このサイトは「質疑応答」「プログラミング知識の収集と拡大」等を図る場所であって、**「著作物(創作物)を披露する場所では無い」** ということです。

このサイトの質問/回答に書かれている内容は、「解決したい課題の説明」とその「解決のための知識/方法」であって、質問自身に引用されていたり、コメントで紹介した裁判所判事(公開当時)の記事に書いてあるような、「著作物(創作物)」では無いでしょう。

[著作権法の守備範囲](https://system.jpaa.or.jp/patents_files_old/201311/jpaapatent201311_137-155.pdf) の2ページ目(印刷物としては138ページ目)

> 著作物につきましては，著作権法 2 条 1 項 1 号に定義規定がございまして，「思想又は感情を創作的に表現したものであって，文芸，学術，美術又は音楽の範囲に属するもの」と定義されています。したがって，まず第 1 に，思想又は感情を「表現」したものでなければならない，第 2 に「創作的」に表現したものでなければならない，第 3 にそれが文芸，学術，美術，音楽の範囲に属するものでなければならない，ということでございます。したがいまして，「表現」それ自体でないものや，表現上の「創作性」のないものは，著作権法の守備範囲から外れてしまうということになります。

「学術」の範囲とは言えないことも無いでしょうが、「思想又は感情を「表現」」とか「「創作的」に表現」という範囲からは外れるでしょう。

主張している人の記述内容が「著作物(創作物)」であるというのなら、それは逆にこのサイトの「対象範囲外」であると考えられます。

---

コメントに対して：

私も好きにして良いとは思っていません。
そのためのヘルプページでの各種宣言と解説でしょう。
本当に好き勝手していたら、元の投稿者から抗議があるだろうし、通報やペナルティもありますよね。

[スタック・オーバーフローの行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)
[スタック・オーバーフローのマニフェスト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto)
[コミュニティで大切にしたい価値観](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values)
[自分の投稿を他の人が編集できるのはなぜですか?編集はどのように機能しますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)
[誰かが何か悪いことをしているのを見つけたら？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)

ただ元の人の言う「一字一句変えてはいけない」ような主張は、このサイトの目的にそぐわないので、それを主張するなら投稿しないで閲覧だけしていた方が良いでしょう、という感覚です。

そのように主張する人の投稿を敢えて編集することも無いでしょう。

Comment: 法律家ではないので完璧に正しくはないかもしれませんが、これは非常に微妙な問題のはずです。たとえば、昨今 OSS のプログラムにはライセンスを付与しておくのが一般的になっています。これは仮にプログラムに著作権が認められた場合でもライセンスを通じて OSS として使えることを担保するためのものです。つまり、プログラムが著作物になる可能性があります。どの程度のプログラムに著作性が認められるかについてはいくつか判例がありますが、スタック・オーバーフローに投稿されるコード片たちも場合によっては著作物になる可能性があります。このため、「著作物ではないから好きにしてよい」という方向性にするのは無理があるはずだと私は考えています。