# コメントが　投稿できません、何故？

Tags: サポート, コメント

[ネコ語の語尾を編集して「ですます体」にするのは問題ないか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1649/%e3%83%8d%e3%82%b3%e8%aa%9e%e3%81%ae%e8%aa%9e%e5%b0%be%e3%82%92%e7%b7%a8%e9%9b%86%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%be%e3%81%99%e4%bd%93-%e3%81%ab%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ae%e3%81%af%e5%95%8f%e9%a1%8c%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%81%8b/3542?noredirect=1#)
ですが。
"

此方コメントで、

行き過ぎた　発言と、
　　　　　　　　　　　←　28日明朝　3行挿入

【内容、】
　　　　　　　　　　　　　マニュフェストの　背景を、
　　　　　　　　　　　　　不適切にも　軽んじ、
　　　　　　　　　　　　　相互理解努力が　足りなかったと、
感じ、

謝罪と　ご提案を、
求めたい　旨、
詳細も　含め。
"

コメントを、

書き込もうと　したのですが、
コメントボタンが　反応せず、
何故か　書けませんでした、

何故ですか？
"

何とも、

いまだ　馴れない、
もので、
お手数をかけ　申し訳ない。

Answer (score 4):

当サイトにおいては [信用度](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) というモデルを採用しており、[コメントを付ける際にも一定以上の信用度が必要となる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) 仕組みになっています。

詳しい説明は上記リンク先のヘルプページや [ツアー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour) ページなどを参照していただきたいですが、信用度は他のユーザーからの投票で上下するようになっています。

コメントにも一定の制限を設けているのは、「質問のやり取りとは関係のない内容」や「スパムからの荒らし」等を防ぐために設けられており、これはこのサイトに登録したばかりのユーザーすべてに適用される仕組みです。(あなた一人が特別にできなくなっているわけではありません)

例外として、「自分自身の投稿」と「自分が投稿した質問にぶら下がる回答」に対してはいつでもコメントができるようになっています。

興味を引く質問や回答を投稿したりすることで自然とプラスされていくと思いますが、一方でこのサイトで扱う範囲とはかけ離れた内容だったり、"質が低い" と判断された場合、(メタにおいては) 提案に同意出来ない場合などにマイナス投票される場合があります。

投票は賛否両論の場合もありますし、仮にマイナス票が入った場合でも投稿を改善することで後からプラス票に転じることもあります。誰かからコメントがついた場合には、単なる批判ではなく見直しのヒントと受け取ってみてください。

Comment: 有難うございます、
"
そうか　そうですよね。
"
"
しかし、
"
此の　様に、
此方には　コメントでききながら、
彼方では　同時に、
駄目なのですよ？
"
メタだからですか？

Comment: 追加説明と　しましては、一方では　不可能、他方では　可能、しかも　ほぼ同時刻に。　此は　何故か？　との　疑問なのですね。　ですので、「評価性だからです、」とのご指摘には、追加説明なき　内では、些かにも　疑問を、挟んで　しまい兼ねないのですよ。

Comment: 又、
"
よりよき　方向を、
目指す　範囲内には。
"
"
抑もから、
"
批判を　恐れず、
行わなければ、
"
達成されない　ものも、
ある中で。
"
"
ご指摘は、
"
此の　辺りに、
どのような　知見を、
持って　示されたか、
"
此の　点も。
"
"
とても、
"
興味深い　点だと、
思うのですね。
"
"
ですのでね、
"
やはり　追加説明を、
求めたく　思うのですが、
"
如何でしょうかね。
"
"
例示しますとね、
"
あくまで　一般論としてですが、
虐め蔓延環境で　虐めは、
"
是正が、
当然で　必須である、
事は、
"
疑いようもなく　当たり前ですが。
"
"
他方、
"
当事者間では　絶不評を、
買い、
"
暴力を　受ける、
事すら、
"
想像に　難くない、
位、
"
ですよね？
"
"
では、
"
》不評と、施行当然事項と、
》何方を　優先しなければ、
》ならないか？
ですが、
"
触れるまでもない　事ですよね？
"
"
では、
"
不評を　必ずしも、
気に　すべきでしょうか？
"
不評を　受ける、
他者顔色を　害す、
等　事は。
"
"
必ず、
"
避ける　べきでしょうか？

Comment: @nouble 私がここで回答したのはあくまで「コメントできないのはなぜか」に対してのみです。追加の疑問に対しては本文中に **例外として** で説明済みです。

Comment: cubick様、
"
有難うございます。
"
"
伺います、
"
其れは　何時からの、
事ですか?
"
"
と、
"
申しますのも、
私は　過去、
50に　達した、
事がなく、
"
尚　コメント投合が、
できております。

Comment: このスレッドは「自分が投稿した質問にぶら下がる回答」にあたるのでコメントが付けられる状態です。

Comment: 失礼しました、コメント趣旨を　変えさせて、頂きました。　　連れても、対応変更を　頂けますか？