# 句読点の無い投稿について

Tags: 討議

時折「句点(。)」もしくは「句読点(、。)の両方」を含まない投稿を見かけることがあります。
1つ2つ程度ならタイプミスの可能性もありますが、自分の意志で敢えてそのような投稿をしているように見受けられます。

もちろん句読点が無くても文章は読めます。意識的に行っているなら文章を書いた人の"個性"と捉えることもできるでしょう。

**関連:**

- [ネコ語の語尾を編集して「ですます体」にするのは問題ないか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1649)
- [句読点として「，．」を使うのは推奨されないか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1464)

一方で、ある程度の長文になってくるとやはり文章としての"不自然さ"があり、(個人的には)読みにくいと感じるのも事実です。

ヘルプページのいくつかでも句読点に言及している箇所があります。

> - [スペリング、文法、および句読点は重要です！](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
> - [(高く評価された質問は) 文法や句読点ができるだけ正しく使用され、読みやすい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited)

仮にこれらを「善しとしない」としても、句読点が無いだけを理由に質問をクローズしたり、これらを付け加えるだけの編集が良いとは思いません。

これらの投稿は("何もしない"を含め)、どのように扱うのが適切でしょうか？

---

**参考:**

英語版のメタでも文法や句読点に関する話題がいくつかありますが、英語がかならずしも得意ではないユーザーが集まることが前提である点は事情が多少異なってくるのかなと思います。

[How to treat bad English sentence syntax and typo hell?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322657) における [コメントの一つ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322657/how-to-treat-bad-english-sentence-syntax-and-typo-hell#comment342065_322657) が私の感じている感覚に近いです。

> Punctuation is a little like the application of white space in code. Sure you could technically write an entire class without a single new line, but ... few people would easily understand the code if you did ;)
>
> 句読点はソースコード内の空白の有無に少し似ています。確かに、改行を1つもせずにクラス全体を記述することは可能です。…しかしそのようなコードを簡単に理解できる人はほとんどいません。

Answer (score 4):

> 時折「句点(。)」もしくは「句読点(、。)の両方」を含まない投稿を見かけることがあります。
>
> 仮にこれらを「善しとしない」としても、句読点が無いだけを理由に質問をクローズしたり、これらを付け加えるだけの編集が良いとは思いません。

私は、句読点が極端に少なく読みづらい投稿については、**投稿の趣旨が変わらない程度であれば編集しても良い**と思います。一方で、句点がないことで読みづらくなる場合は想像がしづらく、編集による改善を行なう必要を感じませんでした。

いずれにせよ、もしその編集を行なうことに迷いが生じたならば、**投稿者とコミュニケーションを取る**べきだと思います。

---

句読点が極端に少ない原因として、以下のようなものを思いつきましたが、いずれにしても「読み手側の負担が大きい場合、文章を改善する余地が残っている」という印象です。

- 打ち言葉は、一度に交わされる文章量が少なく、比較的短時間のうちにやり取りが行なわれる。このような場合には、句読点を省略し、可能な限り早く文章を入力することが多くなるため、その習慣に引きずられて句読点が少なくなる。
- 考えたことをそのまま打ち込み、投稿するときに校正を行なわないため、自然と句読点が少なくなる。
- [忙しい同僚に話しかけているつもり](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)になりすぎている。

また、句読点の極端に少ない文章は、ネコ語の語尾では発生しない、**構文上の重大な変化を起こしうる**という問題があります。さらに、句読点は文章にまとまりを作る働きがあるため、句読点を追加することで、文章の意味が明確になるだけではなく、視覚的にも分かりやすくなります。

---

スタック・オーバーフローの[ツアーページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)によれば、スタック・オーバーフローは、「プログラミングに関するあらゆる質問の詳細な回答集をみんなで作り上げること」を目標としています。この目標を達成するためには、質問者の問題を解決するだけではなく、その**投稿が有益な情報として蓄積されてゆく**ことも重要です。

> ### スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ
>
> **スタック・オーバーフロー** は、職業プログラマーから週末プログラマーまで、プログラミングに情熱をそそぐ人のためのQ&Aサイトです。ユーザーによるユーザーのためのQ&Aコミュニティの集まりである、Stack Exchange ネットワークの一部として運営されています。目標は、プログラミングに関するあらゆる質問の詳細な回答集をみんなで作り上げること。ぜひあなたの力を貸してください。

投稿が有益な情報として蓄積されるためには、書かれている内容そのものだけではなく、**後からの視認性**も重要になります。また、編集の却下理由のひとつには、「編集機能は投稿をより**読みやすく**、**探しやすく、より正確に、使いやすく**するために使われるべき」と書かれています。

以上の 2 つから、句読点によって文章の明確さ、読みやすさを改善することは、編集のための十分な動機になり得ます。

> 編集機能は投稿をより読みやすく、探しやすく、より正確に、使いやすくするために使われるべきですが、この編集はいずれにも該当しません。この編集は不要、もしくは却って投稿を読みにくくしています。

とはいえ、句読点の有無だけで文章の読みやすさが決まるわけではないため、場合によって編集するかどうかの対応が変わってくると思います。また、編集権限によって変更された投稿は、更新された投稿としてトップページに表示されますが、必ずしも誰かが変更内容を確認するとは限らず、**元投稿の意図が失われたままになる可能性**があります。

そのため、もしその改善が正しいかどうかに迷いが生じた場合には、投稿へコメントを追加して改善を求めたり、編集が投稿内容の意図と適合しているかを投稿者に確認したりするなど、慎重な対応が求められると思います。

Answer (score 2):

電子メールスタイルの1文ごとに改行して段落間は空行というスタイルの場合、文末の（後ろに改行が続く）句点を省略するのはインターネットのチャットにおいて昔から存在する慣習的記法ですから、むしろ通常の表記として扱われるべきでしょう。
おそらく、句点のみがない投稿の大半はこれに分類されるはずです。

読点に関しては、省略することで文の意味が一意でなくなってしまい、質問や回答の意図が正しく伝わらなくなる可能性が高いですから、正しい位置に挿入されていることが望ましいでしょう。

Answer (score 2):

対応としては、「ここは○○という意味ですか？」といった風によく分からなかった点を具体的にコメントするのが第一歩かなあ、と思いました。

[Igaguri さんの回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3101/19110)にあるように書き方として過度に不自然という訳ではないので、どちらかの方針に揃える編集を第三者がいきなりするのは不自然、という立場です。コメント等で一度確認をとってみるのが安心かなと思いました。その反応を踏まえて、実際に問題であれば編集するのが良さそうです。

追記：どのくらいであれば勝手に編集を行ってよいかは、ヘルプに[「投稿の意味を明確化する」ことが編集の理由になる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)と書かれているのが参考になります。つまり、意味が曖昧な文章があり、たとえば質問の文脈や質問者さんとのやり取りの中でその部分の意味が確定したのであれば、編集しちゃって良いと思っています。

あくまで意味の明確化を目的とすることが大事です。たとえば「自分の好みの書き方」に揃えることを目的とするのは違うでしょう。投稿されて時間が経っており質問者さんとコミュニケーションをとるのが難しい場合などは、それが意味の明確化になっているかどうかが判断の基準にできます。